# How to test changes to atom language grammars.

Tags: atom-editor

I'm looking to modify a language grammar in atom. However I'm not sure how to reload the grammar in order to test my changes. Do I need to quit and restart each time?

Comment: If you're testing the package as a dev-package, run atom in dev mode, make your changes to the grammar cson file, then reload atom (Ctrl-Alt-R in windows) to view your changes. You can highlight different spans to view the styles applied to them.

Comment: How does one run atom in dev mode?

Comment: run `atom --dev` from the CLI or go to View -> Developer -> Open in Dev mode and select the appropriate folder. But before that you should go to your package directory and run `apm link --dev`, this will create a symbolic link to ~/.atom/dev/packages; you will be able to see your linked package there. So when you open atom in developer mode  your development package will be enabled. See this [thread](https://discuss.atom.io/t/how-are-you-supposed-to-execute-packages-youre-working-on-while-developing-them-i-e-to-test-them/9888/6)

Comment: You can also just reload the window with `View > Developer > Reload Window` menu option or `Ctrl + Shift + F5` on Linux.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [grammar-live-reload](https://atom.io/packages/grammar-live-reload) was made for that purpose, so it's probably the most convenient way.

> Reload automatically editors when grammars files (.cson) changes [...] Only editors that are affected by the selected language are reload[ed].

Otherwise, you can open the command-palette and run *Window: Reload* (this will also show its shortcut). You can do the same in from the developer tools' command-palette by running *Reload Page* or *Hard Reload Page*.